# Find constant term in a quadratic given the quadratic’s definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given that the area bounded by the function $
y=3x^{2}+4 x+k
$ , the $x$ axis , $x=2$ and $x=3$ is equal to 25.
Find $k$

My approach:

We want the value of $k$ so that:

$$
\int_{2}^{3}\left(3 x^{2}+4 x+k\right)dx=25
$$

Then, a non rigorous approach would be to evaluate the integral and solve for $k$. Yet, how could we prove that the function doesn't change from being under the x-axis to being over the x-axis on the given period? That would give us another solution for $k$.

Comment: The range of $3x^2+4x+k$ on $[2,3]$ is $[20+k,39+k].$ If that range included $0,$ the area between the function and the $x$ axis could not possibly exceed $(3-2)((39+k)-(20+k))=19.$ But as you can see from the first posted answer, if you count regions below the $x$ axis as "positive" area then you still have two solutions for $k.$

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $3x^2 + 4x$ is increasing in $[2, 3]$ with minimum value $3\cdot 2^2 + 4\cdot 2 = 12 + 8 = 20$, so there are no feared crossings for any $k \ge -20$. Now 
$$\int_2^3 (3x^2 + 4x) \, dx = \left.(x^3 + 2x^2)\right|_2^3 = (27 + 18) - (8  + 8) = 29$$
and 
$$\int_2^3 (3x^2 + 4x + k) \, dx = \int_2^3 (3x^2 + 4x) \,dx + \int_2^3 k \, dx = 29 + k$$ 
so $k = -4$ gives one answer.  Since you seem also to be considering absolute area, we can solve $$29 + k = -25$$ as well to get $k = -54$.

Finally, there is no chance of the integral equalling $25$ when the graph crosses the $x$-axis in $[2, 3]$, because for that range, the whole shape fits inside two boxes with bases $r-2$ and $3-r$, both of height $19$.

Comment: Could you please further explain the last point? Why couldn’t the function have any zeros on this period?